# Migrate from rails 3.0.0 to rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing on a linux machine and am using rails 3.0.0 but am to move it to a windows machine which have rails 3.0.3 installed.I would like to know how to migrate my application from 3.0.0 to 3.0.3..thanks .

Answer (score 1):

in your gemfile, write `gem 'rails', '3.0.3'` instead of `gem 'rails', '3.0.0'`

i don't think there are substantial differences between these versions so that should do it

Answer (score 1):

Change the Gemfile from

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
```

Run

```
$ bundle update rails
```

Then run the rake task

```
rake rails:update
```

Make sure all your tests pass

```
rake test
```

Comment: thanks @simone i tried it but after starting the server nothing comes on in my browser..it keeps on loading for ever..am using ruby version 1.8.7

Comment: Did you run the test suite? Are there any failing tests?